# Spacy loading custom language model

Tags: spacy

I have a custon model for Bulgarian language. I have packaged it by running:

```
!spacy package ./models_custom_bg/model-best/ packages --name custom_bg --version 0.0.1 --code custom_bg_latest.py
!pip install packages/custom_bg_custom_bg-0.0.1/dist/custom_bg_custom_bg-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

The model was successfully installed:
[pip_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6AFV.png)

However, I still can't load it. Both
`nlp = spacy.load( 'custom-bg-custom-bg')` and
`nlp = spacy_conll.init_parser("custom-bg-custom-bg", "spacy")`
give me
error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom-bg-custom-bg'**.

Comment: Couple of things to check. 1. Replace `-` with `_`. 2. Is that the right name and not like, `custom_bg` just once? Check `pip freeze` 3. Did you restart your kernel after installing?